# How do i pass data through ui-view (UI-Router)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using multiple named views to nest them.
What I want to do is pass some data from the div invoking the template into the template itself.

Something like this

```
<div ui-view="inputtext" data-value="0"></div>
<div ui-view="inputtext" data-value="1"></div>
<div ui-view="inputtext" data-value="2"></div>
```

I want the same template but passing different data to it.

How can I achieve that?

This is how I have the states

```
.state('project', {
      url: "/project/:projectId",
      views: {
        'project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/project.html"
        },
        'group@project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/group.html"
        },
        'task-1@project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/task-1.html"
        },
        'inputtext@project' : {
            templateUrl: "templates/modules/inputtext.html"
        }
      }
```

Inside 'project' I have multiple 'group'
inside 'group' I have multiple 'task'
and inside 'task' I want to show multiple 'inputtext' but with different values each

Comment: You can use the ui router params, or my personal favourite, use a factory

Answer (score 1):

```
function whatyouwannaget()
{


     var scriptUrl = "url";
     $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        } 
     });
     return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stateparams of the ui-router

Let your **HTML** be

```
 <a ui-sref=".detail({id: show.id})">{{show.name}}</a>
```

and your route configuration be like this
 .

```
   .state('app.subscribers.detail', {
    url: 'detail/:id',
    views: {
        'detail@app.shows': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/partials/show-detail.html',
            controller: 'showCtrl'        
        }
    }

});
```